# How to show grid data like this using RowDataBound

Tags: asp.net

I have a question

My grid have column

```
-Name-----------From--------To----------Rate---
Amenity         8/8/2012    8/9/2012    50.00
Amenity         8/6/2012    8/7/2012    50.00
Amenity         8/9/2012    8/10/2012   50.00
Amenity two     7/28/2012   7/31/2012   0.00
Amenity two     8/3/2012    8/4/2012    0.00
```

How can I get this structure at my front end

```
-Name-----------From--------To----------Rate---
Amenity         8/8/2012    8/9/2012    50.00
                8/6/2012    8/7/2012    50.00
                8/9/2012    8/10/2012   50.00
Amenity two     7/28/2012   7/31/2012   0.00
                8/3/2012    8/4/2012    0.00
```

The duplication in `Name` - I just want to show it just one time. How can I do this?

Comment: What control are you using for the grid?  The GridView?  A DataGrid?  A third-party grid?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a DataGrid (since you mention the `RowDataBound` event), the classic way to do it would be:

1. Create a string variable at the page level and call it something like "lastAmenityName".
2. Put the following code in your DataRowBound (this is from memory, so it may not be quite right):

..

```
string amenityName = ((yourobject) e.Row.DataItem).AmenityName;
if(amenityName != lastAmenityName)
     e.Row.Cells[whatevercolumn].Text = amenityName;
else
     e.Row.Cells[whatevercolumn].Text = "";
lastAmenityName = amenityName;
```

Comment: string amenityName = ((yourobject) e.Row.DataItem).AmenityName;in this line what is ment by my object...protected void grdHotelAmenity_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            string amenityName = ((grdHotelAmenity) e.Row.DataItem).AmenityName;
            if (amenityName != lastAmenityName)
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = amenityName;
            else
                e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "";
            lastAmenityName = amenityName;
        }  this is my code

Comment: By "yourobject" I meant whatever type of item the `e.Row.DataItem` was:  a `DataRow`, a `DataRowView`, or an EntityFramework object with its own name.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested GridView to display the way you mentioned.

[image]

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Date
{
    public int DateId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
}

public List<User> Users
{
    get
    {
        return new List<User>
            {
                new User {UserId = 1, FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe"},
                new User {UserId = 2, FirstName = "Marry", LastName = "Newton"},
                new User {UserId = 3, FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Black"}
            };
    }
}

public List<Date> Dates
{
    get
    {
        return new List<Date>
            {
                new Date
                    {
                        DateId = 1,
                        UserId = 1,
                        FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("8/8/2012"),
                        ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(" 8/9/2012"),
                        Rate = 50.00M
                    },
                new Date
                    {
                        DateId = 2,
                        UserId = 1,
                        FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("8/6/2012"),
                        ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime("8/7/2012"),
                        Rate = 50.00M
                    },
                new Date
                    {
                        DateId = 3,
                        UserId = 1,
                        FromDate = Convert.ToDateTime("8/9/2012"),
                        ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime("8/10/2012"),
                        Rate = 50.00M
                    },
            };
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = Users;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        var user = e.Row.DataItem as User;

        var gridView2 = ((GridView) e.Row.FindControl("GridView2"));

        gridView2.DataSource = Dates.Where(d => d.UserId == user.UserId);
        gridView2.DataBind();
    }
}

<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView2" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FromDate" HeaderText="From" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ToDate" HeaderText="To" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Rate" HeaderText="Rate" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```